# Cannot seem to remove UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Undoubtedly another silly question, as, once again, I'm missing something fundamental no doubt.

I have the following in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CRPUserNameViewController.h"
#import "CRPLegalViewController.h"
#import "CRPMainInformationViewController.h"

@interface CRPInitialOpenViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CRPUserNameViewController *vcUsername;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CRPLegalViewController *vcLegal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CRPMainInformationViewController *vcMain;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *ncMain;

@end
```

I'm simply trying to get a `Navigation Controller` to load and become the `rootViewController` replacing the current `UIViewController` with the following code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

_vcMain = [[CRPMainInformationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
_ncMain = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_vcMain]

self.view.window.rootViewController = _ncMain;
[self.view.window addSubview:_ncMain.view];
```

Shouldn't be that hard!! It seemed to work before! Even if I add:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I cannot see the `Navigation Controller`. I'm adding the blue background just to make sure if it is still there!

What am I missing as once again it's driving me mad? How can I use Core Data with no trouble, but not get the `Navigation Controller` to show. Sigh!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using storyboards?

Comment: Good question. I like the challenge of not using them? Amongst other things.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the navigation controller's view as a subview. Setting it as the root view controller already does that.

Comment: @rdelmar: I agree. Even with the line removed, the UIView is still present and doesn't seem to be removed.

Comment: Have you tried presenting it as a modalVC, just to see if it's being built properly?

Comment: Where do you have that code? Have you logged self.view.window to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar: It's currently in `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController`. Appears self.view.window is nil. Why would that be happening? Have looked and it's due to being called in `viewDidLoad`. I've changed it to `viewDidAppear`. Sigh. Now to wonder why!

Comment: No need to wonder. The window property is nil until the view has been added to the window as a subview, which it hasn't been at the time viewDidLoad is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I had placed the code in a place where the window had not even been instantiated. So, that was the cause of all my problems. Thanks for all the answers provided though. Some of them really helped ...

Although still need to work out the difference between when to use ViewDidLoad and ViewWillLoad ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in the AppDelegate, there is the only place you can set the rootView. If you do it in a UIViewController, you are probably setting a root from the root.

Comment: Not true sadly. Many posts state you can set the `rootViewController` at any point throughout the app. I've just been doing it in viewDidLoad. Apparently, the window is connected when `viewDidLoad` is called. But is when `viewWillAppear` is called.

Comment: Oh my bad then, but makes sense that it doesn't work on viewDidLoad then, I understand that's how you've done it before, but, what is wrong with doing it in viewWillAppear instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with view controllers avoid at all cost manually adding or removing their `view`s and try to use a higher level method such as switching `UIWindow`'s `rootController`.

Advantages:

- The SDK will take care of adding/removing/adjusting the actual views for you.
- The view controller will get retained automatically.
- Orientation changed, `viewWillAppear:` and all other controller-related events will get properly called.